# Whats the point in using metadata in HTML?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I started HTML again yesterday and I'm confused. Why are we supposed to use meta tags if it's not on the site?

Answer (score 4):

There's a multitude of `<meta />` tag types serving different purposes, but in essence there's two broad categories:

**Search engine and other crawlers**

- May use `<meta name="description" content="Some description">` for the search results page ([reference for google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/snippet)) or for inline link preview.
- `<meta name="keywords" content="some, tag">` was used for search keywords, but at least [google doesn't use it anymore](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag).
- [OpenGraph metadata](https://ogp.me) is mostly used by social media sites like Twitter and Facebook to display preview images and additional information inline, when a user posts a link (Twitter calls this "cards"). These include `og:image`, `og:title`, `og:audio`, `og:video`, `og:site_name` and [many more](https://ogp.me/#types).
- [Google uses some more for various purposes](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/special-tags)
- Some services uses additional proprietary types, like `<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />`.

**Instructions to the user agent**

- `<meta charset="UTF-8">` specifies the charset.
- `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` instructs mobile browsers how to scale the viewport.
- With [`<meta http-equiv="..." content="..." />`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp) the browser can be instructed to "add" some HTTP headers. For example:

  - `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">` refreshes the page every 10 seconds.
  - `<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="default-src 'self'">` adds a content security policy.

In summary: They're used to add different kinds of metadata and processing instructions.

Answer (score 1):

In relation to the above answers, metadata pretty much just tells the browser how to handle certain things, or what to show when your site appears on a search page.

If you look at the below image, the `<meta name="description" content="Site description">` metatag tells the browser to show people the description: "Learn all about Wolves in the United States and North America."

[image: This image]

The rest of the metatags and what they do/did are in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `<meta>` tag defines metadata about an **HTML** document. Metadata is data (information) about data.
Metadata is used by browsers (how to display content or reload page), search engines (keywords), and other web services.